# Activity feed on NO-SQL storage

Tags: mongodb, facebook, android-activity, notifications, nosql

HI...i have been thinking about a notifications system...which send users an alert when data has arrived for some subscription their made or a friend has made some activity (facebook style).

The thing is i would like to storage it using a no-sql database (mongodb, cassandra) but i cant still figure out how to know when data has changed...should i handle that myself? or the no-sql databse?...like registering a callback??...or just making a query every n seconds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you want a message queue and not a database.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has a [tailable cursor](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors) that you might find useful for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

You also may want to check out Redis pubsub queues.  http://redis.io/topics/pubsub